# I wanted to know about the working of "printf" function in c. For example for the print statements used in below code the outputs are different why?

Tags: c

## how come the pointer gets printed even with `%d`

```
int main()
{
    int  s=5  ,t  ,**p  ,*n;  
    n=&s;  
    p=&n;  
    printf("%d",n);    
    printf("\n%p",*p);  
    return 0;   

}   
//answer for first print statement is purely integers    
//answer for second one  is hexadecimal
```

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Bathsheba How did you write such a short comment? Or there is a privilege for that?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You have to be very rich.

Comment: @Bathsheba what's UB?

Comment: and can someone tell me whats the problem with the question as I already got downvoted? It was literally what I wanted to ask?

Comment: `%d` is the format for a signed integer, but `n` is not - blow up (or print something unexpected).

Comment: @Aditya `%p` is for pointers, but you gave it an `int`.  What did you expect would happen?  [P.S. The reason for the downvotes is that this sort of question has been asked many, many times before.]

Comment: @Aditya "undefined behaviour". C is full of it.

Comment: @steve I think u did not get the question. I know that some integer value will come as output but I wanted to know despite the thing being pointer why it didnt showed any kind of warning or anything.

Comment: @Aditya Ah.  In that case, see the answer I'm posting now.

Answer (score 1):

This is [undefined behavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You must match the type required by the format specifier to the type of the value passed.

Comment: u mean not defined in c?

Comment: @Aditya It's a well-known term, many things in C lead to what the standard calls "undefined behavior". Basically if you break the rules, anything can happen and it's not the compiler's fault. Please read the link.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you made it clear that you wanted to know "why it didn't show any kind of warning or anything".

`printf` is an example -- the best-known example -- of a *variadic* or "varargs" function.  It does not accept one, fixed list of arguments with an exact number of predefined types.  Every time you call `printf`, you call it with a different number of arguments, and the only way to determine how many arguments and what types they should be is to go through the format string looking for the `%` signs.

The `printf` function itself knows how to do this.  At run time, when you call it, it goes through the format string looking for `%` signs, and each time it finds one, it looks at the following letter to determine what type of argument it should fetch next.  But at run time, there's no mechanism to double-check what type of argument has actually been passed -- `printf` just blindly fetches a value (typically from the stack) that's assumed to be of the correct type, and prints it out assuming it had the correct type.

But that was at run time.  The only way you could get a warning or error message at compile time would be for the *compiler* to go through the format string looking for `%` signs, and match them up with the actual arguments it can see you're passing.

Once upon a time, that wasn't a reasonable thing for a compiler to do.  But times have changed, and today this is actually something that a good compiler *does* do!  Here's what I got when I compiled your code using clang on my Mac:

```
warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'
```

And here's what I got when I compiled it with gcc, using the `-Wall` option:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
warning: unused variable ‘t’
```

So, the bottom line is: use a modern compiler (and remember to request warnings), and it should tell you about problems like these.

P.S. In a comment I said, "`%p` is for pointers, but you gave it an `int`."  But I misread your code.  Your first `printf` call uses `%d`, and passes `n`, but `n` is `int *` which is a pointer, so that's wrong.
Your second `printf` call uses `%p`, and passes `*p`.  In your code, `p` is an `int **`, a pointer to pointer to `int`, so `*p` is a pointer-to-`int`, and that call is therefore (mostly) correct.